# Reading a Protected View Excel file using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read an Excel .xlsx file that has been saved from an Outlook attachment. My security setting (which I cannot change) puts this file into `Protected View` mode.

If I try and read this file via `xlsxwriter`

```
import xlsxwriter
xlsx = 'protectedfile.xlsx'
wbWriter = xlsxwriter.Workbook(xlsx)
print( len(wbWriter.worksheets()) )
```

I get the answer `0`.

If I open the file in Excel, I get this banner:

[image]

If I choose "Enable Editing", Save the file and Quit Excel, the file is now accessible via `xlsxwriter` and correctly lists the number of worksheets.

If I look at the initial downloaded file in File Explorer Properties it tells me the file is blocked. I can remove this flag using `os.remove(filename + ':Zone.Identifier')` but the workbook remains in `Protected View` with zero sheets.

If I extract the `:$DATA` stream using PowerShell and copy that to another file:

```
> $a = get-content ./protectedfile.xlsx:':$DATA' -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0
> set-content ./another.xlsx -Encoding Byte -Value $a
```

The `another.xlsx` file opens in Excel without the Protected View warning, but `xlxswriter` still does not see any sheets.

One solution is to use `win32com` to open, edit and save each file in the background, along the lines of:

```
import win32com.client as wc
xl = wc.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
pv = xl.ProtectedViewWindows.Open('protectedfile.xlsx')
wb = pv.Edit()
wb.Close(True)
```

But this is slow, cumbersome and requires Excel to be started and shut down.

Is there a programmatic alternative for removing the Protected View flag so that `xlsxwriter` can access the contained worksheets?

**UPDATE**: after @jmcnamara's salient comment, I have found I can read the protected view .xlsx using `pandas` and `read_excel`: ie with `openpyxl` as the engine. I can then write the DataFrame dictionary back to a new file, which is a more efficient conversion than automating Excel. Eg this code copies the data over (though loses some formatting):

```
import pandas as pd

def unProtect(oldXlsx,newXlsx):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(newXlsx,mode='w',engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        for k,dfSheet in pd.read_excel(oldXlsx,sheet_name=None).items():
            dfSheet.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=k,index=False)

unProtect('blocked.xlsx','unblocked.xlsx')
```

I am still interested to know how the structure of the .xlsx has been changed as the proprietary code (not Python) I am using is failing to unpack the zipped xml of the protected view file.

Comment: Protected mode notwithstanding XlsxWriter cannot **read** an Excel file. It can only write them. Have a look a OpenPyXL instead.

Comment: @jmcnamara That's a big help. It seems I can read the .xlsx (using pandas `read_excel` with openpyxl as the engine: the default for xlsx).